# Vector of vectors in R but not is matrix

Tags: r, vector

I have a little problem using vector of vector.
In my routine R, : don't know how create and assign elements to a vector of vectors but not is a matrix Some columns or rows  have more elements than others.Then be able to call one of the elements

for example the vector :

```
v=( c(1,2,3) , c(3,4,5,1,3,4,1,) , c(3,4) , c(3,3,3,3,3,1,2,) )
```

then, `v[3]` should show `(3,4)`

I tried a for `for (i in 1:k){t[i] <-  x[v[[j]](x) > w[j]]}`

but is bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list:

```
myList <- list(c(1,2,3), c(3,4,5,1,3,4,1,) , c(3,4), c(3,3,3,3,3,1,2,))

> myList[3] 
[[1]] 
[1] 3 4
```

Comment: yes, but sizes of arbitrary vectors? and elements too?

Comment: A list can potentially store _anything_ of _any_ size.  I believe this is the way to go if you want to store vectors of arbitrary size.

Comment: Tried this      `myList=list(NULL) .   myList[1]<-c(1,2,3), myList[2]<- c(3,4,5,1,3,4,1)...` but is impossible. help me please

Comment: Use `myList[[1]] <- c(1,2,3)` instead of `x[1]<-c(1,2,3)`